# pentaho CDE, report designer justify_interval query from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, reporting, pentaho, postgresql-9.4, pentaho-cde

when i try to execute this query `select justify_interval('2000000 second');` in postgreSQL (pgAdmin) it work perfectly i had this result : **23 days 03:33:20** , but when i use it into Pentaho Report designer or Pentaho CDE , i had this result : **00 years 00 months 23 days .....**   , my question is : there are any methods to get the same result like pgAdmin in Pentaho, i don't want to have fileds with **0** [Screenshot from PEntaho Report Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBWZH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your value to string in SQL query:

1. You can simply cast your value to text or varchar in SQL:

   ```
   select justify_interval('2000000 second')::text as justify_interval;
   ```

   or

   ```
   select cast(justify_interval('2000000 second') AS text) as justify_interval
   ```

   **Output:** `23 days 03:33:20`
2. If you want to have more control on resulting value, you can extract different parts of interval using `date_part()` or `extract()` SQL functions. Then you'll be able format these parts as required and append text in required language:

   ```
   -- common table expression just to avoid writing justify_interval('2000000 second')
   -- in every date_part entry:
   WITH interval_cte(interval_column) AS (
       VALUES(justify_interval('2000000 second'))
   )
   SELECT
       -- trim to remove trailing space, if seconds are null
       -- nullif(*, 0) will make it null if the date part is 0
       -- in this case the subsequent concatenation with ' *(s)' will result in null too
       -- finally(*,''), coalesce will replace null with empty string, so that 
       -- subsequent concatenations will not dissappear:
       COALESCE(NULLIF(date_part('year', interval_column), 0) || ' year(s) ', '') 
       || COALESCE(NULLIF(date_part('month', interval_column), 0) || ' month(s) ', '') 
       || COALESCE(NULLIF(date_part('day', interval_column), 0) || ' day(s) ', '') 
       -- FM prefix will suppress leading whitespace,
       -- 00 will output leading zeros if number has less then two digits
       || to_char(date_part('hour', interval_column), 'FM00') || ':'
       || to_char(date_part('minute', interval_column), 'FM00') || ':'
       || to_char(date_part('second', interval_column), 'FM00') AS justofy_interval
   FROM interval_cte
   ```

**Output:** `23 day(s) 03:33:20`

Comment: thank you for this helpfull answer , it works perfectly